Having problems connecting a local Django project to a Cloud SQL database instance
I have a Cloud SQL database running on MySQL 8.0.31. Now, I have a Django 5.1 project that I want to connect the database with (with root permissions). However, whenever I run any python manage.py <django-script-here> (inspectdb, runserver, showmigrations, etc.) command, it results in an error saying
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to server during query')

I'm pretty sure its a Django issue because I can connect to the database through MySQLWorkbench 8.0.22, and I can connect to it locally by using the mysql.connector library.
So, I thought it was version problems but I checked the package versions within my virtual environment and they are all compatible with official documentation to back it up (i.e MySQL 8.0.31 works with Django 5.1).

The answer was a very easy fix.... and I didn't even solve it, so shoutout to my coworker!
So I had my settings.py DATABASES section set up like this:
DATABASES = {
    'default:': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': ...,
        'HOST': ...,
        'PORT': ...,
        'USER': ...,
        'PASSWORD': ...,
    }
}

You should change 'django.db.backends.mysql' to 'mysql.connector.django'.
Also run pip install mysql-connector-python
My coworker just solved it through trial and error, but still, it's frustrating that even if you follow the official documentation of Django, MySQL, Cloud SQL, etc. it won't work and you are expected to troubleshoot from the start.

This, pretty much seems to be documented though? If you're using mysql.connector.django as the engine that means you're using MySQL Connector/Python as the DB API driver, the documentation mentions "Django provides an adapter for mysqlclient while MySQL Connector/Python includes its own." You probably actually had some issue with the version of mysqlclient you were using.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers, mysqlclient was (in bold) the recommended choice. I also had a mysqlclient version that was >= 1.4.3.
For a beginner, I trusted the fact that they emphasized to use mysqlclient, and had the correct version installed, and thought my problem would be related to something else.
Though I do agree, eventually I should've just tried MySQL Connector/Python, but if mysqlclient was the recommended choice, then it should work out of the gate.
